# How to return a json in get_queryset()?

Tags: python, json, django, django-queryset, httpresponse

I want to return a error message in JSON format from a get_queryset() if error occurs. Does anyone knows hot to do it?

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            #some code that returns a queryset
        except:
            return Response({"status": "ERROR!"})
```

But obviously I`m unable to do that.
Does anyone knows how to resolve this?

One possible way is to somehow convert the message into queryset and return it. But I don`t know how to do it!

Comment: This isn't a thing you want to do. `get_queryset` is supposed to return a queryset, hence the name. You need to do this elsewhere in the view.

Comment: `get_queryset` is a method on ModelManager. Do you mind updating your question with the code snippet that includes the Class that implements get_queryset()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that if you want to return a `Response` the `get_queryset()` method is inside a class-based view. As the name says the method itself can only return a `QuerySet`, though inside a view you can raise certain exceptions which are turned into a response by [Django's built-in exception handling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/#exception-handling).

You can eg. raise an [`Http404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/#django.http.Http404)  and Django will automatically respond with 404 response status.

This behaviour you can [customize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) and eg. return a `JsonResponse` instead of the normal response.